# Python matching-item based concatenation of list of sublists?

Tags: python, list, merge, sublist

Without getting too deep, the ***Input*** below represents the following:

[geometry,name,z-coord,key-region, ... ]

Any *key-regions* matching between sublists influence the merger of the  sublists where the *geometry* fields are combined into a single string, and the *name* fields are combined into a single string. All while retaining the remainder of both sublists as they should match.

**Input:**

```
[['Aquitards~:#>0', 'Aquitard 1', 1, '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
['Aquitards~:#>2', 'Aquitard 3', 1, '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
['Aquitards~:#>2', 'Aquitard 7', 1, '4', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
['Aquitards~:#>0', 'Aquitard 8', 1, '4', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], 
['Aquitards~:#>1', 'Aquitard 2', 1, '7', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], 
['Aquitards~:#>1', 'Aquitard 9', 1, '9', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
```

**Current Merging method:**
The code below works, but only for merging pairs of sublists into one.  This needs to be revised or rewritten to enable infinite number of matches merged into one sublist.  I am troubled with where to go from here...

```
        matchList = []
        rawRows = []
        for idxA,rowA in enumerate(tempList):
            for idxB,rowB in enumerate(tempList):
                if idxA!=idxB:
                    if int(rowB[3])==int(rowA[3]):
                        tempRow = [rowA[0]+'}~{'+rowB[0],rowA[1]+';'+rowB[1]]
                        reverseMatchRow = [rowB[0]+'}~{'+rowA[0],rowB[1]+';'+rowA[1]]
                        tempRow.extend(rowB[2:])
                        reverseMatchRow.extend(rowB[2:])
                        if not reverseMatchRow in rawRows:
                            rawRows.append(tempRow)
                            matchList.append(rowA)
                            matchList.append(rowB)
                            continue
                    elif rowB in matchList: continue
                elif idxA==idxB:
                    if not rowB in rawRows:
                        if not rowB in matchList:
                            rawRows.append(rowB)
                        continue
        for row in rawRows:
            if not row in matchList:
                self.rows.append(row)
```

**Current Output:**

The above ***Input*** and ***Merging method*** give the following result to highlight what and how things would ideally be merged.

```
['Aquitards~:#>0}~{Aquitards~:#>2', 'Aquitard 1;Aquitard 3', 1, '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['Aquitards~:#>2}~{Aquitards~:#>0', 'Aquitard 7;Aquitard 8', 1, '4', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['Aquitards~:#>1', 'Aquitard 2', 1, '7', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['Aquitards~:#>1', 'Aquitard 9', 1, '9', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

**Conclusive Question:**

-How would one string-merge the first two items from each sublist within a list of sublists for all sublists based on matching index items; furthermore remove the now merged sublists original source sublists, and retain any non-matching sublists - resulting in a single *cleaned-up* list of sublists?

For example, the *key-matching* index for each sublist below would be [3];

***Idealized Input:***

```
    [['Aquitards~:#>0', 'Aquitard 1', 1, '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
['Aquitards~:#>2', 'Aquitard 3', 1, '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
['Aquitards~:#>3', 'Aquitard 5', 1, '4', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
['Aquitards~:#>4', 'Aquitard 4', 1, '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
['Aquitards~:#>2', 'Aquitard 7', 1, '4', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
['Aquitards~:#>0', 'Aquitard 8', 1, '4', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], 
['Aquitards~:#>1', 'Aquitard 2', 1, '7', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], 
['Aquitards~:#>1', 'Aquitard 9', 1, '9', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
```

***Idealized Output:***

```
    ['Aquitards~:#>0}~{Aquitards~:#>2}~{Aquitards~:#>4', 'Aquitard 1;Aquitard 3;;Aquitard 5', 1, '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['Aquitards~:#>2}~{Aquitards~:#>0}~{Aquitards~:#>3', 'Aquitard 7;Aquitard 8;;Aquitard 4', 1, '4', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['Aquitards~:#>1', 'Aquitard 2', 1, '7', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['Aquitards~:#>1', 'Aquitard 9', 1, '9', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: Any clues? (About what you want, i.e., whether this works, and if not, whether that's the actual or the desired output, and what the other one is)

Comment: To initial comments: Edited the original post to reflect your  (good) suggestions.

Comment: There is no question anywhere in this post. The title has a question mark but isn't built as a question either. You might want to explain what you are trying to do, and what problems you have.

Comment: @Emile: Thank you, updated based on your advice.

Comment: You still haven't even told us whether your code works.

Comment: @Stefan Pochmann:  I must be poor with words - as I used 'works' and 'working' incorrectly in the original post.  Have simplified to hopefully remedy this. Thanks.

Comment: Katalpa: I still can't figure out what you're trying to do. The top of your post should have some intro about what you're trying to do, and then maybe what input you have (it's good), what you want your output to look like (you don't have that), and then maybe you can go to showing your code or your incorrect output.

Comment: @Emile:  Hopefully the changes I have just made help answer your callings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain

is the place you want to start. to make your first pass easier for you to understand and tune-up i recommend declaring the sublists as their own variables and breaking out the slices you want to use ahead of the .chain() call. it will be much easier to understand the 'under the hood' usage that way until you're confident with it.

Comment: it's an extremely useful tool to have once you get used to it. being able to string together an arbitrary number of iterable items in the way you want is really useful.

Comment: lost network access and came up with the solution listed - not as elegant (yet) as the link you provided, but maybe I can trend it that way.  Wisdom appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the process of having no network access to scour for clues - this is the solution I came up with...

**Current Working Solution:**

```
        inherentZones = []
        for sublist in tempList:
            keyZone = int(sublist[3])
            if not keyZone in inherentZones:
                inherentZones.append(int(sublist[3]))
        possibleZones = [[] for x in xrange(len(inherentZones))]
        for sublist in tempList: 
            placementIndex = [inherentZones.index(a) for a in inherentZones\
                              if int(a)==int(sublist[3])]
            if not len(possibleZones[placementIndex[0]])==0:
                possibleZones[placementIndex[0]][0]=\
                             possibleZones[placementIndex[0]][0]+'}${'+str(sublist[0])
                possibleZones[placementIndex[0]][1]=\
                             possibleZones[placementIndex[0]][1]+';'+str(sublist[1])
            else:
                possibleZones[placementIndex[0]]=sublist
```

**Example Input:**

```
[['Aquitards~:#>1', 'Aquitard 9', 1, '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], 
['Aquitards~:#>2', 'Aquitard 3', 1, '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], 
['Aquitards~:#>2', 'Aquitard 7', 1, '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], 
['Aquitards~:#>1', 'Aquitard 2', 1, '3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], 
['Aquitards~:#>0', 'Aquitard 1', 1, '3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], 
['Aquitards~:#>0', 'Aquitard 8', 1, '3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
```

**Example Output:**

```
[['Aquitards~:#>1', 'Aquitard 9', 1, '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], 
['Aquitards~:#>2}${Aquitards~:#>2', 'Aquitard 3;Aquitard 7', 1, '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
['Aquitards~:#>1}${Aquitards~:#>0}${Aquitards~:#>0', 'Aquitard 2;Aquitard 1;Aquitard 8', 1, '3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
```

Not sure how rapid it is compared to other options (considering its the only solution I have got to work).

That being said, it works great merging as many sublists with matching keys as needed.  Maybe someone sees some refinement?